# Render specific partial in a parent folder with jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm using jbuilder in my rails project.

On a route I can get the index of my devices or show a device with his id.

But a User have many Devices. So on the route `users/:id/devices` I would like to be able to get the devices. For the moment I have a partial called `_device.json.jbuilder` with the path `app/views/api/v1/devices/_device.json.jbuilder`. I would like to call it from `app/views/api/v1/users/devices.json.jbuilder`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is to give the full path inside `app/views`. In that case :

`/api/v1/users/devices.json.jbuilder` look like this

```
json.partial! '/api/v1/devices/device', devices: @devices
```

Comment: Can i give a relative path?